# How to color columns' numeric cells while ignoring character vectors represents NA in gt package from R

Tags: r, gt

For a dummy data as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:4, v1 = c("/", "0.2", "0.3", "0.4"), v2 = c(0.8, 
0.2, 0.1, 0.5), change = c("/", "0", "-0.2", "0.1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

With code below, I can easily coloring `v2` with `gt` package from R since its data type is `numeric`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

df %>%
  gt() %>%
  data_color(
    columns = "v2",
    colors = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = paletteer::paletteer_d(
        palette = "ggsci::red_material"
        ) %>% as.character(),
      domain = NULL
      )
  )
```

Out:

[image]

Now I would like to color `v1` as well (pls note this column's dtype is `char`) and display `NA` with `/` (since the output figure will be used in report, so I wish to `\` or `-` as symbol to represent `NA` or `NaN` rather than using R's default NA symbol).

So my question is it's possible to do so? If yes, how? Thanks for your help at advance.

[image]

**Edit:**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
library(paletteer)

na_palette <- paletteer::paletteer_d(palette = "ggsci::red_material") 
na_palette[1] <- "#FFFFFFFF" # replace  "/" with white

df %>%
  gt() %>%
  data_color(
    columns = "v2",
    colors = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = paletteer::paletteer_d(
        palette = "ggsci::red_material"
      ) %>% as.character(),
      domain = NULL
    )
  ) %>%
  data_color(
    columns = "v1",
    colors = scales::col_factor(
      na.color = "white",
      palette = na_palette %>% as.character(),#use the palette
      domain = NULL
    )
  )%>%
  data_color(
    columns = "change",
    colors = scales::col_factor(
      na.color = "white",
      palette = na_palette %>% as.character(),#use the palette
      domain = NULL
    )
  )
```

Out:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add another `gt::data_color` call to your pipe:

```
df %>%
  gt() %>%
  data_color(
    columns = "v2",
    colors = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = paletteer::paletteer_d(
        palette = "ggsci::red_material"
      ) %>% as.character(),
      domain = NULL
    )
  )%>%
  data_color(
    columns = "v1",
    colors = scales::col_factor(
      palette = paletteer::paletteer_d(
        palette = "ggsci::red_material"
      ) %>% as.character(),
      domain = NULL
    )
  )
```

in that case you just need to change the `scales::col_numeric` to `scales::col_factor` which sets colors for your character values

**edit:** if you want to set the `/` to white:

```
na_palette <- paletteer::paletteer_d(palette = "ggsci::red_material") # get the palette

na_palette[1] <- "#FFFFFFFF" # replace  "/" with white


df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    change = factor(change, levels = change),
    v1 = factor(v1, levels = v1)
  ) %>% 
  gt() %>%
  data_color(
    columns = "v2",
    colors = scales::col_numeric(
      palette = paletteer::paletteer_d(
        palette = "ggsci::red_material"
      ) %>% as.character(),
      domain = NULL
    )
  ) %>%
  data_color(
    columns = c("v1", "change"),
    colors = scales::col_factor(
      palette = na_palette %>% as.character(),#use the palette
      domain = NULL
    )
  )
```

Out:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, the color represent values, if it's larger or smaller, so I updated code, pls test with updated `palette`.

Comment: should still work with `scales::col_factor` for v1, I updated the answer

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. BTW, is it possible set no color for cell `/` since it represent `NA`s?

Comment: i adapted my answer, you might also think of `n = NROW(df)` in `paletteer::paletteer_d`, so every value also gets a color

Comment: I apply your code to `change` column, but a value use `na_palette` instead of `/`.

Comment: I changed my answer: if you change the data type of the columns to factor with the correct levels it works, the problem was before that the `col_factor` set the wrong levels

Comment: Problem perfertly solved, many thanks.

Comment: Seems we can use alternative solution as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68911736/special-zero-value-in-gt-tables